# Is there a way to omit the achievements in Google game service?

Tags: google-play-games

If I only need the leadboard feature and thus I do not want to add any achievements in the games, is there anyway to do this? Currently I can see that at least 5 achievements are required before publishing in the developer console.

I know that adding 5 dummy achievements can work, but I am wondering if there are any settings on this that I missed.

Thank you very much for help/clarification!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, you have missed nothing.  Dummy achievements will work fine to allow you to publish.

Also, you can set them all to hidden so they won't show up at all.

Comment: Hi @user2346305, I have implemented same thing but, means implemented leaderboard and added dummy Achievements. But I got below alert in Google play console "Detected incorrect implementation
Your game has incorrectly implemented the following Play Games services: Achievements."